# Hidden layers make useless scrollbars appear

Tags: layer

So I've been trying to figure that one out for a time now, and I feel like I'm out of ideas.

So, my website has layers in it that make scrollbars appear even when they are hidden. It makes it possible for the user to scroll my website even when there is no need to. I would like to know if there is a way to make the browser scrollbars appear ONLY when such layers are set on visible.

I've been trying to use div overflows, but the problem is that since those divs are placed at a set top value, it makes the upper content of the layers hidden when scrolling down.

Anyone knows how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:none` style instead of `visibility:hidden` style. `visibility:hidden` only make the an element invisible, but its space/layout is still calculated.